# Node-red can't connect to broker to produce messages (Kafka and Zookeeper are in docker containers)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, node-red

I'm creating an app that shows real-time data coming from IIoT.

My whole app is in docker containers with Kafka and Zookeeper running without a problem, I execute node-red (in my local machine) and it connected successfully but when I tried to produce messages from IIoT in node-red it gives "Connection down started queuing messages".

This is my docker-compose.yml (for Kafka and Zookeeper):

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
    volumes:
      - zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper
    networks:
      - app_backend_network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=LISTENER_BOB://kafka:9092,LISTENER_FRED://127.0.0.1:29092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=LISTENER_BOB://kafka:9092,LISTENER_FRED://127.0.0.1:29092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=LISTENER_BOB:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=LISTENER_BOB
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 29092:29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka
    networks:
      - app_backend_network
```

Host : 127.0.0.1:29092

[Node-red producer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiweb.png)

Host : 127.0.0.1:9092

[Node-red producer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZQ8Z.png)

I tried to connect "TH" directly to messages and I received messages with no errors the problem here is probably connecting to the broker.

I forgot to mention that when I set up Kafka in my local machine without docker it worked just fine.

Any help, please!

Comment: Is the IIoT on the same host machine as your broker? Are you using 127.0.0.1 on the IIoT as the host name to connect to the broker?

Comment: @wxker, Non, the IIoT sends messages using MQTT to the node-red server and node-red send them to Kafka.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/abhishekkarigar/b30cbd8261434f8e427a3594d39c98a2

Comment: above link has proper confluent zookeeper and kafka in docker-compose xml, might help

Comment: basically you are running node-red outside the container ?

Comment: `KAFKA_LISTENERS` should not use specific IPs. Should be `protocol://0.0.0.0:port` or removed. You should also not be using the latest tagged images, and should prefer a specific version